# trying to retrieve name from current data selected

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

t
I have data shown about a band that matches a id selected, im then using the band_id and getting it to use it else where.
I would like to do the same with Name field but I am having a few problems, its just getting the word array in to the var  $name.

**code**

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';


$Band_id = $_GET['id'];
$name = ['Name']; // trying to get the band name
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bands WHERE Band_id = $Band_id");

echo "<table border = '1'>
<tr>
    <th>Band Name</th>
    <th>Venue</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Buy Ticket</th>
</tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><form name=\"myform\" action=\" order.php\"  method=\"post\">";
        echo " <input name=\"band\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"". $Band_id."\" >";
        echo " <input name=\"bandn\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"". $name."\" >";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Venue']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Category']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Stock']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><button>Buy Ticket</button></td>";
        echo "</tr> </form>";

    }

echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: What is $name for? What data do you want to put in there? Your question doesn't fully make sense

Comment: Saying that is $row['Name'] not what you're after?

Comment: in $name I wish to get the current band Name.

Comment: But how are you getting that information?

Comment: trying to pull it from the query, as the column name is Name

Comment: then surely $row['Name'] is all you need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$name = ['Name']` wont work above the query, and generally wont work at all as its invalid syntax for what you're trying to do. Where you have used `$name` use `$row['Name']`

Comment: Wow was relay that simple, thank you Andy Holmes. I was trying different variations for hours.

Comment: Not a problem :) The amount of times a silly issue like that has left me stumped is ridiculous. Always the simple things :)